# Hibernate multiupdate?

Tags: hibernate

During start of application I'm loading array of objects from DB. How can I refresh/reload all objects based on DB by one Query as it is during start of application.

I do not want to update objects one by one.

Br.

Answer (score 1):

clear your app cache (array holding the db objects), clear the session which loaded the objects if still present and call the function loading the objects at startup time again.